# Change companyweb to intranet.companyname.com

Tags: group-policy, sharepoint, windows-sbs-2011

We're having issues with a sister company that has an SBS 2011 Standard server on site on a separate domain to ours - they have problems editing documents via SharePoint, whereas my manager can get in just fine externally.  We noticed that the SharePoint address was `http://companyweb/` and wondered if that was an issue, since that was the address they used and my manager used intranet.companyname.com instead.

Our attempts to change it, however, have been almost, but not quite, entirely fruitless.

First, we looked at group policy.  I can see in the Windows SBS User Policy that the Internal Web site link is shown as `http://companyweb` - so I went to edit it, only to find that Internet Explorer Maintenance **was not shown at all under Policies -> Windows Settings**.

[image: Listing of options under Group Policy Manager. No IE Maintenance to be seen.]

*EDIT 2015-05-21: This is because IE11 was installed, which removes the IE10 policy objects.  IE11 ones are only available in 2012 onwards or as a separate download.*

Next place I looked was the console.  The website is listed under Websites (as shown below) but there is absolutely no option to change the address here, either.

[image: SBS Console showing websites.]

Changing around names in IIS has resulted in just as much change to the situation as a whole.

The only other option I can think of is to create a new website in IIS using companyweb as the address, and redirect it to the "proper" SharePoint address.  Before I resort to that extreme, is there anything else I can do, or are we stuck with this because apparently nobody wants to change it?

Comment: 1. Is the problem getting into SharePoint or editing documents in SharePoint, because your question is contradictory (they have problems editing documents via SharePoint, whereas my manager can get in just fine externally)? 2. Companyweb is the internal name and URL (created during setup) and is probably not relevant to the actual problem. 3. Reverse everything you've done to this point and then clarify the problem; Can they access Sharepoint? Can they edit documents in Sharepoint? Does the problem occur internally and externally? What is the exact problem with accessing/editing documents?

Comment: 1. They can't edit documents internally, but my manager can edit them externally. 2. Maybe, maybe not. 3. Nothing's been done at this point.  Yes.  No.  Internal only using `http://companyweb`.  I believe they were having security prompts that prevented saving documents, I'll ask my boss who asked me to make that change and get back to you.

Comment: When they open documents in SharePoint they should be getting a prompt to open them for Edit or Read Only. Were/are they getting this prompt? If so, do they get it both externally and internally?

Comment: Ok, I've got a bit more intel on the issue - turns out when they add new documents to the Document Library, it complains about missing document property fields that are not at all missing.  This happens whether they use `http://companyweb` or `http://intranet.companyname.com`.